# Why are all Planck base units square roots of expressions in $\hbar$, $G$ and $c$?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

Section 2.3.1 "Base units" in "[The International System of Units](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf/2d2b50bf-f2b4-9661-f402-5f9d66e4b507)" defines length, mass and time as the dimensions of "base units".  The corresponding [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#History_and_definition) are defined as:

$$length=l_P=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}$$

$$mass=m_P=\sqrt\frac{\hbar c}{G}$$

$$time=t_P=\sqrt\frac{\hbar G}{c^5}$$

How does one account for the fact these are all square root expressions?

Comment: What do you mean by "have physical meaning"? Can you provide some examples of things that you think "have physical meaning" and some examples of things that you think do not "have physical meaning"?

Comment: The Planck length in $d$ spacetime dimensions is $\ell_p=\sqrt[d-2]{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}$, so the square root can be viewed as being a consequence of the fact that $d=4$.

Comment: I pruned the question down to the point that it is now focused on mathematical physics and its relation to Planck units so as to avoid opinion.

Comment: Your assumption should be called into question: which is actually the more fundamental of the two? The Planck area or the Planck length? In $d$ dimensions - as has already been (indirectly) noted - the corresponding quantity ħG/c³ is the "d-area" - the analogue of area for d dimensions. That, in itself, is a very strong hint that there is something fundamental having to do with the action integral, in relation to d-2-dimensional subspaces! Take this in conjunction with the fact that the coupling coefficient for GR is κ = Numbers×G/c³ (not ...×G/c⁴, people!), and this says something about ħκ.

Comment: From a purely mathematical point of view, the answer is very simple. It's because when you write the dimensions of these three constants in terms of length, mass, and time, you get a matrix whose determinant is plus or minus 2.

Comment: Please DO NOT try to edit answers in ways that fundamentally clash with the author's intent. I am specifically saying that it is only one of the stuff that is being a square root, and the interconnections between the other units causes all the others to also become square roots. I am not at all claiming that mass and time are also intentionally chosen to be square roots. If you think that is the case, then you are sorely mistaken.

Comment: My apologies if I violated stackexchange etiquette.  The reason I submitted -- for your approval -- the edit I did is that it seemed to me to be a clearer exposition of what I thought you were trying to convey.  Obviously, as you say, I was sorely mistaken -- at least in your intent.  What I would question is whether I am mistaken in granting special significance to Hamiltonian generalized coordinate areas in the context of Planck units -- as apparently others have done in a variety of places I've looked, in part, based on my interpretation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is really just a lot of stuff being internally connected. If any one of them is made of square root, then most of them will also be.

First of all, you say that

> The exception for area is obvious since it is a derived dimension by squaring the fundamental length dimension.

This is actually a misconception. What is considered a derived thing and what is considered fundamental, is itself a choice. Here, it is clear that area is chosen to be the fundamental, and length to be the derived. This is similar to how in SI units, it used to be the case that Amperes were the fundamental and Coulombs the derived, even though theoretically we might want the opposite choice. It is quite fashionable these days to pick areas to be the fundamental; quite a lot of physics seems to say that areas are better-defined than lengths. For example, black hole entropy is proportional to areas rather than lengths or volumes. Phase space areas are conserved by Hamiltonian dynamics, even though that is not a usual area.

---

What is happening here is that, because area is taken to be fundamental, length is thus going to be a pure square root. Since $\ell=ct$, this means time is also going to be a pure square root. In the simplest, dimensionless form of Schwarzchild black hole metric, fractions appear as $\frac{2M}r$, which means that mass and length have the same units, and hence mass will also inherit the pure-square-rooted-ness of length.

Temperature is just badly defined; it does not have to be defined at all, since temperature should just be measured by energy units.

We should just not use Planck's charge. Just use electron charge, as usual. Or rather, maybe the smarter thing to do is to fix Planck's charge definitions so that we can arrive at electron charge, and use that to fix the definitions of the area, thereby fixing everything else.

In conclusion, you are simply seeing some interconnected parts of the physics.

Comment: ***//"We should just not use Planck's charge. Just use electron charge, as usual. Or rather, maybe the smarter thing to do is to fix Planck's charge definitions so that we can arrive at electron charge,"//*** $$ $$ My goodness, I must disagree with that.  Planck units are not based on any prototype object or particle but ***only*** on the fundamental properties of free space.  No specific object or particle gets into the definitions of Planck units.  So the electron is an object.  It has an amount of mass and it has an amount of charge just as do other specific particles.

Comment: ***//"Temperature ... does not have to be defined at all, since temperature should just be measured by energy units."//***
$$ $$
That, I agree with.  Temperature in kelvin (scaled by the Boltzmann constant) is nothing other than a measure of energy per particle per degree of freedom.

Comment: With the appearance of the Planck's constant, some form of understanding of quantum theory comes in. Maybe that is "not based on any prototype object or particle", but so should the magnitude of the fundamental unit of charge. All free particles have charge that is a multiple of this fundamental unit; it is not specific to either of electrons or protons or what other particle. (Quarks are not free.) We could just swap the Planck's constant for the fundamental charge unit and get something more sensible. A unit system ought to also prioritise convenience.

Comment: ***//"All free particles have charge that is a multiple of this fundamental unit;"//*** $$ $$ We know that.  But Planck units are not Stoney units.  There is no prototype object that is the basis of Planck units, only the properties of free space.  Why not chuck $G$ and define the electron mass as the unit mass?  If we do that, we get Atomic units.  Planck units are not about atoms or particles.  No special objects.  Any object has properties like mass or diameter or charge or spin that are numbers that can be compared to their counterparts of other objects.